# Error Can't resolve all parameters for EditPage al recargar mi Ionic App con -ionic serve

Tags: html, ionic, typescript, angular4, navigation

Tengo este error al recargar mi Ionic App con *-ionic serve*:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for EditPage: ([object Object],
>   [object Object], [object Object], ?).

Este es el typescript de EditPage (*edit.ts*):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from "../home/home";
import { IconsPage } from '../icons/icons';

@Component ({
  selector: 'page-edit',
  templateUrl: 'edit.html'
})

export class EditPage {
  position: number;
  notification = this.homePage.allNotifications[this.position];
  newDoneText: string = 'Hecho';
  newCancelText: string = 'Cancelar';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public iconsPage: IconsPage,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public homePage: HomePage,
  ) {
    this.position = navParams.get('position');
  }

  openIcons() {
    this.navCtrl.push(IconsPage);
  }

  changeThisIconName() {
    this.notification.iconName = this.iconsPage.returnIconName();
  }
}
```

Y así es como la llamo  y le paso los parámetros (*home.ts*):

```
openEdit() {
    this.navCtrl.push(EditPage, {position: this.positionEditNotificationInAllNotifications});
  }
```

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está dentro de tu constructor:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for EditPage: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).

Cada elemento `[object Object]` representa un parámetro dentro de tu constructor, es decir, que `navCtrl` es el primero, `iconsPage` el segundo, `navParams` el tercero y `homePage` debería ser el cuarto, ¿existe el componente en la ruta que declaraste?

Usualmente en el constructor solo se inyectan providers/servicios, te sugeriría revisar si es tu caso es realmente necesario inyectar los componentes así, si necesitas utilizar una misma funcion/datos en dos componentes distintos, podrías migrar los procesos a un servicio.

Comment: Sí, es lo que dices. Cambié la estructura con providers y ahora no tengo errores. Muchas gracias!!